# Should disposable objects be passed in?

Tags: c#

In a code review a co-worker changed my code to pass in a Stream as a parameter.  He said this was to ensure that the responsibility to dispose of the object is clear to the caller.  In a sense I can empathize.  I would prefer the object creator to also be responsible for cleanup.

On the other other hand, neither method makes the need for a `using` any more clear.  I prefer the simpler method call as well.

Take

```
    public static TextReader Serialize<T>(T obj) where T: new()
    {
        if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
        return Serialize<T>(obj, null);
    }
```

VS

```
    public static void Serialize<T>(T obj, TextWriter outbound) where T : new()
    {
        if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
        Serialize<T>(obj, outbound, null);
    }
```

Is there any technical reason to add the extra param?

Comment: If we take a cue from the .NET Framework itself, for example, `XmlSerializer`, the stream tends to be passed in as a parameter.

Comment: May be a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It strictly depends on your code architecture.

I, personally, like the second approach (even if it adds one more argument) where *definition* of the function *states* that it will not close/dispose a stream, but it's up to the Caller.

This is very useful in case when you're going to call the same functions on the same stream, cause if you imagine, that every function call will close and reopen the stream, it becomes resource consuming operation.

Answer (score 4):

You might have a TextWriter open already. That is why I'd prefer the second version. Also, it reduces the scope of what the Serialize method does: It serialized, but it does not open anything. Opening is a different concern.

Answer (score 1):

As the project evolves, programmer(s) maintaining the code in the **first** approach may not remember that it's the calling code's responsibility to close the stream (especially in non-trivial cases). Callers would have to rely on documentation for doing the right thing and everybody reads documentation, right? ;)

The **second** approach better ["balances" resources](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/balance-resources). It makes it much clearer where the separation of responsibilities lies.

Answer (score 0):

The overloaded Serialize-T method CREATES the stream? If that's the case I prefer #1 becuase it makes the 'using' simpler:

```
using (var stream = Serialize(a_T)))
{
    // Do something else with the stream?
}
```

On the other hand, it might be better for the caller to SUPPLY the stream, in which case you'd like to pass one in a la option 2.